# Has someone tried to keep a CD at a further distance from the CD-pickup-reader?

Tags: infrared, proximity-sensor

So, I basically want to know the range of the IR light that comes from a CD reader/writer (KSS-213C). I used an IR sensor(IR Photodiode) to detect the light that comes from the pickup reader, but until I go very close to the lens, I'm not getting any reading. (Following image source: google.com)[image]

Also, if I remove the lens, will the range of the IR laser increase?

If you need any other information, I will add it along later.

Comment: They had to know for build quality, x +\- y can be expensive when y is small ie the positioning has to be very precise - as you are finding out...

Answer (score 1):

http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1944121.pdf 
Should tell you most of what you want to know. The lens focus is 3.6mm so that would be where the CD or your sensor needs to sit for the beam to be focused. Removing the lens will cause the beam to spread out over a large area as opposed to focusing on a spot so i'm not sure what you would achieve in doing that. In terms of the 'range of IR light' the data sheet says 760-800nm wavelength so no measuring needed :)

Comment: I'm not repairing this device but trying to hack it and use it for something else. I basically need an IR source but with the ability to use lenses. So I thought the CD reader would be a nice and cheap way to do so. But I need the IR light to travel at least a couple of centimeters. Is that possible here?

Comment: Yes, the focs of the *lens* is about 3.6cm, but will the light completely dissipate after say 5cm? Has anyone tried to detect at such a distance using a really good sensor is what I meant to ask. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The further away from the light source the greater the dissipation. If you want to keep the light focused at a further distance you would need to create your own lens. I'm sure you will still detect some light at 5cm as is but without a clear idea of what the end goal that you want to build its difficult to help further. In terms of 'has anyone tried to detect at such a distance' sure, probably, but I don't know them :) Perhaps IR LEDs might be more suitable? what is the application of your device

Comment: So what I'm trying to create is like an IR source and I need to be able to focus that beam on different points on height. So something like spectacles but for Infrared light. Different focal lengths would focus on different points. So I should have instead first tried for an IR Source, but wouldn't be able to move a lens up and down with such precision. Hence I went in the direction of CD readers, where I have the ability to move the lens and change the focal point. But what I need is of a higher dimension, i.r of order of centimeters

Comment: That's a start but before you can go further we need constraints. What height range are you working within nm, mm, m? what medium is the light projecting onto? is a sensor reading the emitted IR light? and most importantly what is the application ie purpose, so you want to focus IR light at varying height but why?... All these questions are important to produce a specification so you select correct parts and design accordingly

Comment: I'm working in centimeters. All of the instruments are in the open air. Yes, a sensor is at the opposite end to detect the IR light. So this of this as a model of a CT scanner. So instead of an X-ray source, I have an IR source. And instead of a detector array, I have detectors on the opposite end. And the lenses would do the job of creating a cone beam source, just like CT scanners.

Comment: Well a mechanism to change the lens on the fly to gain different focal points is a very difficult and expensive way around it. Also trying to use this device for the cm range will be incredibly difficult when its designed to work at mm distances, I imagine much larger lens will be needed. You could use some form of actuator perhaps a servo to maintain 3.6mm distance from the sample you are 'scanning' so the focal point is fixed but the device is moved

Comment: Ok, forget about the moving lens part. What if I said, I just need one lens fixed relative to the source. Is this possible? So if I remove the lens from the cd reader and attach a cheap lens outside on my own would that be a better approach? And forget about the revolving part, I got that figured. I just need to somehow have a good amount of IR light focussed about a few centimeters from the source

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96336/discussion-between-theandyengineer-and-danush).